# CKEditor (.net) disappears on postback where HttpResponse hijacked to deliver download stream

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, postback, httpresponse

I have a page with 2 tabs on it (using bootstrap's `.tab-nav`). In one tab, inside an update panel, I have a CKEditor 4.x instance. In the other tab, I have a button that pushes a CSV file via HttpResponse (initiates a download). This download button triggers a full postback since partial postbacks can't push streams for download.

The problem is that after I initiate the download, when I switch back to the tab with the CKEditor instance, it's vanished.

Any ideas how to fix? I *suspect* it is directly related to the fact that I'm hacking the HttpResponse from the server to deliver the download, but why would the CKE instance disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it: Every time someone opens the tab with the ckeditor on it, I use cke's js API to restore it.

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <textarea class="ckeditor" id="ckeditor1" />
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    // Every time someone opens the ckeditor-containing tab, replace the CKEditor if it is missing
    $("a[href='#tab2']").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        if (CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor1 == null) {

            // Decode the textarea content
            var t = $("#ckeditor1");
            t.val(CKEDITOR.tools.htmlDecode(t.val()));

            // Show the ckeditor instance
            CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor1", { toolbar: 'CustomToolBar' });
        }
    });
```

Just using `CKEDITOR.replace` didn't work because the content is encoded when stored into cache. I had to upgrade cke from 4.0.2 so that I could decode the content using `CKEDITOR.tools.htmlDecode` when restoring the instance.